# EWS HttpHeader Content-type

Tags: c#, http-headers, exchangewebservices

I've followed Microsoft's [Get started with EWS Managed API client applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/get-started-with-ews-managed-api-client-applications) tutorial, in an effort to build an application that will get specific items from a mailbox on an Exchange server.

It seems that after the initial auto-discover operations succeed, no matter what kind of request I send through the API, I get a response back containing the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/plain; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.
```

With `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.TraceEnabled = true`, the trace of a typical request looks like this (this one is generated by calling `Folder.Bind(service, "IT", propSet)`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Trace Tag="EwsRequest" Tid="1" Time="2019-03-01 14:42:02Z" Version="15.0.913.15">
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
      <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" />
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
      <m:GetFolder>
        <m:FolderShape>
          <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
        </m:FolderShape>
        <m:FolderIds>
          <t:FolderId Id="IT" />
        </m:FolderIds>
      </m:GetFolder>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
</Trace>
```

It looks like the Content-Type header is missing altogether, so the server sees the request as `text/plain; charset=utf-8`. It shouldn't be a problem to add `Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8` to requests that the `ExchangeService` object makes, but the member Dictionary `HttpHeaders` is not settable (see the interface in [ExchangeServiceBase](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/blob/master/Core/ExchangeServiceBase.cs#L865)).

Any idea how I can either send the server an acceptable request with the EWS Managed API, or configure the target Exchange server so that it accepts the requests I'm sending?  I've come across lots of related SO questions, but none with an actual answer to this problem.

Comment: I also have the same problem. I don't know how to solve it

Comment: I'm beginning to think that this comes from compiling against .NET Core, which most installations of Visual Studio Code use, instead of the .NET Framework that comes with Visual Studio.  If I get to return to this project, the next thing I'm going to try is installing Visual Studio and seeing if using it to compile the project makes a difference.

Comment: In the EWS fork by sherlock1982 (https://github.com/sherlock1982/ews-managed-api) find EwsHttpWebRequest.cs class.
There, in the GetResponse method, right after setting message content (line 91):

message.Content.Headers.Clear();
message.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");

The issue is becouse of incorrect content type of the HttpRequestMessage, not request itself.

Hope this helps - I know, the answer is one year late... :)

Comment: @Mikk I figured the way to resolve this was by forking the library. :P Bummer! I ended up abandoning the project that prompted this question, since it was an exploratory effort.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error and the only clue I could find was this thread.

I eventually fixed it by switching to Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.NETStandard -v 1.1.3 (from -v 2.0.0-beta1).